# Filter input by name[] in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a little script that allow me to paste a value into different inputs.

```
<input name="BOO_Price">
<a id="repeatPrice">Repeat</a>
<input name="BOO_Price">
<input name="BOO_Price">
<input name="BOO_Price">
<input name="BOO_Price">


$('#repeatPrice').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var price = $(this).prev('input').val();
    $('input[name=BOO_Price]').val(price);
});
```

It works perfectly.

But now my inputs form are like this.

```
<input name="BOO_Price[]">
```

But this is not working:

```
$('input[name=BOO_Price[]]').val(price);
```

---

Ideally, I do not want to had some `id` or another sort of `classes`.

---

Could you please help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the attribute value with quotes since value contains meta-characters.

```
$('input[name="BOO_Price[]"]').val(price);
```

---

Or escape the meta-character using `\\`.

```
$('input[name=BOO_Price\\[\\]]').val(price);
```